# Cache a variable in groovy

Tags: variables, caching, groovy, elasticsearch, integer

When I try to access the len-variables at the end of the script I get this error: "Cannot iterate twice! If you want to iterate more that once, add _CACHE explicitely."

How can I fix that?

```
def src_str = query_string
def src_arr = src_str.split(' ')

def trg_arr = doc['my_index'].values

trg_arr_sorted = [:]

trg_arr.each {
_index['my_index'].get(it, _POSITIONS).each { pos ->
    trg_arr_sorted[pos.position] = it
    }
}

src_len = src_arr.length
def trg_len = trg_arr_sorted.size()

int[][] matrix = new int[src_len + 1][trg_len + 1]

(src_len + 1).times { matrix[it][0] = it }
(trg_len + 1).times { matrix[0][it] = it }

(1..src_len).each { i -> 
(1..trg_len).each { j ->
    matrix[i][j] = [matrix[i-1][j] + 1, matrix[i][j-1] + 1,
        src_arr[i-1] == trg_arr_sorted[j-1] ? matrix[i-1][j-1] : matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1].min()
    }
}

return 100 - (100 * matrix[src_len][trg_len] / max(src_len, trg_len)) // over here !!!
```

The code calculates a score using the levenshtein distance computed in words. It works perfect except of the scoring in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Okay problem is solved.

I explicitly had to declare cache and positions:

```
_index['lang'].get(it, _POSITIONS | _CACHE)
```

The error wasn't in the last line, but I thought so. I changed the script to debug it, but elasticsearch doesn't reload the new scipt instantly.